# how to crawl only updated parts every run

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to crawl data that could be updated. How do I approach this when I want to schedule the crawler to crawl only the updated parts each time it runs? I am using beautifulsoup.

Comment: Kindly refer to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question on SO. Kindly show some efforts from your side too.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate only new postings you need to find some sort of primary key, that is guaranteed to be unique to each result. This could be the url, the internal id, etc. Once you have found a unique value you need to store it inbetween sessions. For something with fast lookup I would use a set. Here is a basic example that maintains the results you have seen in between sessions using sets and the builtin pickle module.

We will assume you have isolated the results in the list `elements`, and that each element is a BeautifulSoup object with an  `<a>` tag with a unique `href` value.

```py
import os
import pickle

if not os.path.exists('seen.pickle'):  # If the seen file doesnt exist, create it.
    with open('seen.pickle', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(set(), file)

with open('seen.pickle', 'rb') as file:  # Load the seen file so we can reference it.
    seen = pickle.load(file)

for element in elements:
    if not element['href'] in seen:
        # Your own code here
        seen.add(element['href'])  # Add it to seen so it is never parsed again

with open('seen.pickle', 'wb') as file:  # Save the seen file.
    pickle.dump(seen, file)
```